# NPOI How to update cell format in workbook

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, npoi

I'm trying to format cell as follows.

Input "99.99999"
Expected output "99.999"

```
public void UpdateCellToExistingWorkBook(int x, int y, string value,
        string format)
    {
        var sheet = _hssfworkbook.GetSheet(_sheetName);

        try
        {
            var cellStyle = _hssfworkbook.CreateCellStyle();

            if (format != null)
            {
                cellStyle.DataFormat = _hssfworkbook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat(format);
                //cellStyle.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("00.000");
            }

            var cell = CellUtil.CreateCell(sheet.CreateRow(x), y, value, cellStyle);
            cell.SetCellType(CellType.Numeric);

            WriteToFile(_path);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are inputting a string and not a number. Try to save a decimal value to the cell and not a string

Comment: @TheMixy .CreateCell() accepts string, not a decimal

Comment: OK, but can't you omit setting a value at `CreateCell` and then define the cell value afterwords, smth like this: `cell.SetCellValue(decimal.Parse(value));` ?

Comment: @TheMixy For some reason the field is still "General" `var cell = sheet.CreateRow(x).CreateCell(y);
                cell.SetCellType(CellType.Numeric);
                cell.SetCellValue(Convert.ToDouble(value));`

Comment: see my code sample below. Also be aware that "99.99999", cannot be shown as "99.999", because it rounds to "1.000" by Excel if you make the cell numeric. The latter you can only achieve by a string I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my example that works when editing an existing Excel file (note that my Excel is localized to use decimal comma and not a dot):

```cs
public static MemoryStream ListExcel2(string path)
{
    XSSFWorkbook hssfwb;
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, "Test.xlsx"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        hssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        file.Close();
    }

    ICellStyle _double = hssfwb.CreateCellStyle();
    _double.DataFormat = hssfwb.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("#,###.###");

    ISheet sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0);
            
    IRow row = sheet.GetRow(7);
    ICell cell = row.GetCell(1);
    double value = 999.912123123d;
            
    cell.SetCellValue(value);
    cell.CellStyle = _double;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) //creating memoryStream
    {
        hssfwb.Write(memoryStream);

        return memoryStream;
    }
}
```

Output (in the template cell B8 is formatted as "general" and is changed to custom numeric as per the code above):

[image]